# Are sums of sequences decidable?

Tags: computability-theory, sequences-and-series, computational-complexity, nt.number-theory, lo.logic

Suppose that $f,g$ are rational functions with integer coefficients such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)$ both converge. Is it decidable whether
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)$? If this problem is decidable, then what is the computational complexity of this problem? If this problem is undecidable, then what is the turing degree of this problem? I am also interested in answers concerning generalizations of this problem such as when we take double sums or when we include factorial functions and exponential functions as well. This question does not have much to do with my current research. Instead, I am mainly interested in this question out of curiosity.

Comment: This question is harder than I thought it would be.

Comment: decidability would be very surprising

Comment: Isn't the problem equivalent to deciding whether one such series converges to 0? -- Not that this would make the problem easier, though ... .

Comment: except if this happens only when $f=g$...

Comment: To decide this, one would need to know whether numbers such as $\zeta(5)/\zeta(3)$ are rational. In fact, via partial fractions, and Euler-Maclaurin formula this problem is reduces to deciding whether linear combinations of incomplete zeta function are zero or not. 

Comment: Boris, would you care to explain the reduction?

Comment: This is almost exactly equality testing on the real numbers, which is known to be undecidable. In brief, we usually effectively represent a real number as a function computing a sequence (for instance, a sequence of shrinking intervals that converge to that number). Your series representation is almost exactly equivalent. Given two such representations, equality is undecidable; not sure about the Turing degree. For a reference, maybe the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis and "Intro to computable analysis": http://eccc.hpi-web.de/resources/pdf/ica.pdf.

Comment: The problem would be decidable if the following problem was decidable. 

(*) Given two polynomials with integer coefficients $p(x), q(x)$ such that $p(x)>0, q(x)>0$ for every $x>0$, is it true that $\sum \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}=1$?

To approach (*) represent $p(x)/q(x)$ as a linear combination of elementary fractions.  



Comment: There are certainly many nonzero rational functions $f$ such that $\sum f(n)=0$ -- for example you can ensure $\sum_{n=0}^N f(n)$ is an arbitrary rational function which tends to $0$ when $N \to \infty$ (up to the constant term, which is not a problem since we can consider linear combinations of such $f$). Are these the only examples?

Comment: @usul I don't think this is nearly as hard as equality testing on the real numbers, the form of the sum is very special.

Comment: As @Boris Bukh wrote, the problem seems to be equivalent to linear dependence of numbers of the form $\zeta(m)/\zeta(n)$ for integers $m,n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Mark Sapir and @Boris Bukh.  From the way you both mention this, I assume the decision problem of linear dependence of numbers of the form $\zeta(m)/\zeta(n)$ is not known (at least to you two).  Is there reason to believe it is difficult to figure out?  (This is not my area, so for all I know this could be reducible to some big name open problem.  And if it is, I think that would perfectly qualify as an answer.)  

Comment: First, there are only countably many such sums $\sum f(n)$ with $f$ rational with integer coefficients.  So this is far from equality-testing on the real numbers.

Here's an analogue which might shed light.  Consider instead the decidability of $f(x) = 0$, when $f$ is a G-function (in the sense of Siegel) and $x$ is a rational number.  Such decidability would be very close to the decidability of equality of Kontsevich-Zagier periods.  This is at least as strong as Schanuel's conjecture, I'd guess.

Comment: @François Brunault: could you explain how you build such a $f(n)$ ? I don't see it

Comment: @Marty any problem for which we can ask whether it is decidable has a countable input. Otherwise the question does not make sense. For real numbers, the inputs are Turing machines that describe the number (for instance on input $i$ they output the $i^{th}$ digit), so the set of real numbers for which we want to decide equality are the computable ones, and it is a countable set. Still it is undecidable, but not because $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: @D K : Take an arbitrary rational function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ and $g(x) \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$, and consider its discrete derivative $f(x)=g(x+1)-g(x)$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)=0$.


Comment: I think there is a difference between knowing that $\zeta(5)/\zeta(3)$ is irrational and knowing that $\zeta(5)/\zeta(3)$ is not equal to some specific rational number $\alpha$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer - agreed, my bad: I hastily read "rational function" and thought "rational-valued function".

Comment: @François Brunault: You are correct and we really need to be able to find out if for given (finitely many) rational $\alpha_i$ and numbers $x_i$ of the form $\zeta(m)/\zeta(n)$ we have $\sum \alpha_ix_i$ is 0. Of course it is easy to check if the sum is NOT 0, but how to prove the equality is not clear to me. Also I do not know the subject well enough to say that this is a known  open problem.

Comment: Could someone post some details of the proposed reduction? I think that's as good as it gets to answer this question and it appears that some very non-trivial expertise needed to carry out the reduction. When I tried to carry out Boris's outline, I was first perplexed on how to handle the remainder term of Euler-Maclaurin. Then, the connection with incomplete zeta functions <http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.22> wasn't clear. The Hurwitz zeta functions <http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11> looked more promising but even then I ran into deeper convergence issues. I would love to be enlightened!

Comment: @Francois.  I indeed meant Hurwitz zeta function (I misremembered the name). I did not work out the full details of reduction myself, so I did not anticipate the problems with the remainder term in the Euler--Maclaurin. The partial fraction summation yields terms of the form $1/(n-a)^k$ with $k\geq 1$. The $k\geq 2$ terms give the Hurwitz zeta function. For $k=1$ one needs to use Euler--Maclaurin. I do not know how to handle the remainder terms in general, but perhaps Summation #1 from section 9.6 of "Concrete Mathematics" which is a special case could be a start.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that this is an open problem, so I will do the job of (trying to) put this question out of its misery by summarizing  a few of the remarks in the comments. This answer is community wiki.

Replacing $f(n)$ by $f(n)-g(n)$, one may as well ask whether the sum is zero or not.

**Variations:** Suppose one makes the restriction that $f(n)$ is an *even* function, or alternatively (and almost equivalently) consider summations from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Then the degree of $f(n)$ must be at most $-2$, and one has (taking $R$ through a sequence of half integers and $C_R$ the corresponding circle centered at zero):

$$0 = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C_R} \frac{\pi \cos \pi z}{\sin \pi z} f(z) dz =
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(n)  + \sum_{f(\alpha) = \infty}  \pi \cot(\pi \alpha) \mathrm{Res}(f)(\alpha)$$ 
Literally speaking, this is only correct if $f(z)$ has simple poles, but the general case is no more difficult. It follows that determining whether the sum is equal to zero or not is the same as verifying an identity in
$$\overline{\mathbf{Q}}(e^{\pi \beta_1}, \ldots, e^{\pi \beta_n}),$$
for a fixed set of algebraic numbers $\beta_i$. By Schanuel's conjecture, the only such relationships are the "obvious" ones, so in this case one *conjecturally* has an algorithm.

**Periods:** Passing now to the general (no longer even) case but specializing in a different direction: for certain special $f(n)$, the sum in question is a period (e.g. $\zeta(n)$ for $n \ge 2$ an integer). Kontsevich and Zagier raise the question whether determining the equality of two periods is decidable or not; the expectation is that it should be, but there are no real ideas in this direction. There certainly are no known general algorithms for proving equalities.

**General Remarks:** By expanding into partial fractions, one has the general formula:
$$\sum f(n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{r,s} \frac{(-1)^r \cdot r! \cdot A_{r,s}}{(n + \alpha_s)^{r+1}}
 = \sum_{r,s} A_{r,s} \cdot \psi^{(r)}(\alpha_i),$$ 
Where $\psi^{(r)}(z)$ is the Polygamma function, so $\psi^{(0)}(z) = \psi(z)$ is the logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function. Note that this only makes sense when one has convergence, which happens if and only if $\sum A_{0,s} = 0$ (this also means one can replace $\psi(z)$ by $\psi(z) + \gamma$ if you wish). Explicitly, for those who worry about such things, the $r=0$ term can be written (since $\sum A_{0,s} = 0$) as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s} \frac{A_{0,s}}{(n + \alpha_s)}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s} \frac{A_{0,s}}{(n + \alpha_s)} - \frac{A_{0,s}}{n+1}
= \sum_{s} A_{0,s} (\psi(\alpha_s) - \psi(1)) = \sum_s A_{0,s} \psi(\alpha_s)$$

The functions $\psi^{(r)}(z)$ can also be thought of as  Hurwitz zeta functions. The most general hope would be that the only relationships between values of polygamma functions at algebraic arguments are those which are occurring for "motivic" reasons. There's not much to motivate this beyond the related explanations (which are already conjectures) in the easier cases discussed above.